# Request format for communicating with STS

Tags: jax-ws, java-metro-framework

I am trying to connect to MS-Dynamics web service which requires STS based (using windows live id) token. The WSDL contains all the details for getting the token. (wsdl can be seen at https://contoso.api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc?wsdl=wsdl1 )

Is there a way in Metro/Jax-WS to generate code to make a request for the token?